# localStorage.getItem() gives a different result in different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, phantomjs

I am working with PhantomJS. I want to compare the behavior of PhantomJS with Google Chrome while loading the first page of WikiPedia. Based on my observation there is a request generated by both browsers which is triggering differently. There is a parameter in that request which takes a different value in each of these browsers. As I found, there is a line in the JavaScript's file of the WikiPedia from which the browsers start behaving differently. The line is as follows:

```
raw = localStorage.getItem(mw.loader.store.getStoreKey());
```

the value for 'raw' while using Google Chrome is 'null'. But, the value for 'raw' while using 'PhantomJS' is some JavaScript Functions. This difference causes both browsers to behave differently and assign different values to one of the parameters at the end.

I am sure that before executing this line, there is no line for localStorage.setItem() and I am wondering why PhantomJS can load those functions into the 'raw'? Where are these functions coming from? Does PhantomJS have any problem with 'localStorage' command?

Comment: How did you verify that this actually happens in PhantomJS? Have you used the debugger?

Comment: Not a debugger. I have a proxy and used it as a server. I captured all the traffic to see what is going on. I have added different logs among existing functions and hence, I captured that. Actually, I found the reason for this problem which is, PhantomJS does not remove the information in localStorage file automatically. I removed it manually and then, both PhantomJS and Chrome behaved the same. Now my question changed! How can I possibly ask PhantomJS to remove the file for localStorage automatically?

Comment: I completely forgot this little fact. You should provide the answer and then ask the new question. Did you do this in Chrome with the incognito tab or did you run this with selenium so that a new profile is generated? I would think that Chrome will behave the same way as PhantomJS.

Comment: I just added the answer as you suggested. I am using PhantomJS using my own Script in pure JavaScript. I don't use Selenium. Also, I don't use Chrome with the incognito tab. I just remove the History, Cache and the Cookies in Chrome and then set a Proxy for it. I thought after using phantom.exit() command, PhantomJS should remove all the previous information related to previous session. But it seems that it does not do that. I am adding a new question for this. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason for this problem is the fact that PhantomJS, in spite of other browsers like Chrome, does not remove the localStorage file automatically. Therefore, in each run, it uses the previous saved information for a particular website. In order to avoid this problem, we need to remove localStorage file before running PhantomJS.

Comment: As far as I know Chrome doesn't remove localStorage when you exit it. That's what sessionStorage is for. You said in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101378/localstorage-getitem-gives-a-different-result-in-different-browsers#comment44627508_28101378) that you explicitly remove history, cache and cookies. You possibly also removed the localStorage.